# TEXT型カラムの値をINTERVAL型に変換し、その値を別のINTERVAL型カラムに代入する方法

Tags: sql, postgresql

環境: PostgreSQL9.4

現在、0秒〜2日までの時間データを保持するのに、TEXT型カラムdurationへ次のような文字列を保存するようにしています。

- PT10S
- PT1H10M20S
- P1D

このフォーマットはISO8601に準拠している為、例えば次のようにEXTRACT()を使い変換できます。

```
postgres=# SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL 'PT1M10S');
date_part
-----------
        70
(1 row)
```

これをソートする必要が出てきたのですが、文字列のままでは正しくソートされないので、これを次の手順でINTERVAL型に変えることにしました。

1. INTERVAL型の新しいカラムduration_tmpを作成
2. 全レコードのdurationの値をEXTRACT()で変換し、その値をduration_tmpに代入
3. durationを削除し、duration_tmpの名前をdurationに変更

この2. の方法が分からず困っています。一度次のようなコマンドを打ったのですがうまくいきません。

```
postgres=# UPDATE my_table SET duration_tmp = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL duration);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "duration"
LINE 1: ...le set duration_tmp = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL duration);
                                                             ^
```

どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST してしまえば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
postgres=# SELECT CAST('PT1M10S' as INTERVAL);
interval 
----------
00:01:10
(1 row)
```

ですので、

```
SELECT duration FROM hoge_table ORDER BY CAST(duration as INTERVAL);
```

となるかと思います。実環境がないので間違っているかもしれません。

<strike>ところで、例として挙げられた ISO8601 形式の時間データのうち、`PT1D` だけ書式エラーとなりました。</strike>

```
postgres=# SELECT CAST('PT1D' as INTERVAL);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "PT1D"
```

Comment: CASTでうまくいきました。ありがとうございます！
あとPT1Dではなく、P1Dでした。すみません。(・_・;)